# Using Conan with Python3 on Travis-CI

Tags: c++, python-3.x, travis-ci, conan

I have a C++ project that uses Travis-CI and Conan. My Linux build on Travis-CI is failing when it attempts to download libcurl:

```
libcurl/7.61.1@bincrafters/stable: Building your package in /home/travis/.conan/data/libcurl/7.61.1/bincrafters/stable/build/b6dbf799dd7e6d1c740e159bea361666320a3db8
libcurl/7.61.1@bincrafters/stable: Configuring sources in /home/travis/.conan/data/libcurl/7.61.1/bincrafters/stable/source
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:150: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecurePlatformWarning
ERROR: Error downloading file https://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.61.1.tar.gz: 'HTTPSConnectionPool(host='curl.haxx.se', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /download/curl-7.61.1.tar.gz (Caused by SSLError(CertificateError("hostname 'curl.haxx.se' doesn't match 'c.sni.fastly.net'",),))'
Waiting 5 seconds to retry...
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:150: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecurePlatformWarning
libcurl/7.61.1@bincrafters/stable: WARN: Trying to remove corrupted source folder
libcurl/7.61.1@bincrafters/stable: WARN: This can take a while for big packages
ERROR: libcurl/7.61.1@bincrafters/stable: Error in source() method, line 131
    tools.get("https://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-%s.tar.gz" % self.version)
    ConanException: Error downloading file https://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.61.1.tar.gz: 'HTTPSConnectionPool(host='curl.haxx.se', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /download/curl-7.61.1.tar.gz (Caused by SSLError(CertificateError("hostname 'curl.haxx.se' doesn't match 'c.sni.fastly.net'",),))'
The command "conan install .. --build missing" exited with 1.
```

Per the advise in the error, I have tried to get Travis to use Python3 to see if that would resolve the problem but I have had no luck. First I added `python3` to my `packages:` like so:

```
matrix:
  include:
    - os: linux
      dist: trusty
      sudo: required
      env:
        - CC_COMPILER=gcc-7
        - CXX_COMPILER=g++-7
        - BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo
      addons:
        apt:
          packages:
            - python3
            - gcc-7
            - g++-7
          sources:
            - ubuntu-toolchain-r-test
```

But I received the same error as above. Then I tried `alias`'ing the command:

```
install:
  - |
    if [[ "${TRAVIS_OS_NAME}" == "linux" ]]; then
      sudo pip install conan
      alias python=python3
    fi
```

Yet, I get the same results.

How can I get Travis-CI to use python3 for Conan? Or is there another way I can get my `conan install` command to work?

Thank you!

Comment: Wouldn't that happen when using `python3` because you're using `pip` and not `pip3`?

Answer (score 1):

The default CI scripts generated with `conan new pkg/version -s -cilg` might help. They contain something like:

```
linux: &linux
   os: linux
   dist: xenial
   sudo: required
   language: python
   python: "3.6"
   services:
     - docker

matrix:
   include:
      - <<: *linux
        env: ...

install:
  - chmod +x .travis/install.sh
  - ./.travis/install.sh
```

And the install script:

```
pip install conan --upgrade
pip install conan_package_tools

conan user
```

So it is not declared as a package, but defined at the root level, and that seems to be enough to later use it with bare `pip install`.

Comment: When I try this it has the effect of completely messing up my compiler configuration and settings, i.e. I use clang-3.8 but it falls back on the default distro GCC instead, compiler options are not recognized by CMake, and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Well if I am reading it correctly python3 is not the issue here. The error is:

```
CertificateError("hostname 'curl.haxx.se' doesn't match 'c.sni.fastly.net'",
```

So something fishy with ssl.
Python2 does produce insecure platform warning when using ssl / https but it's rarely the issue.

As for python3 on Travis - I personally couldn't get conan to work in CI with python3. 
But basic steps are:

```
   apt:
      packages:
        - python3
        - python3-pip
...
```

To install conan using python3:

```
   sudo pip3 install conan
```

Note that in your example `install` you called `pip` - which installs conan with python3 and it will run by python2 when called from command line despite the alias. The interpreter to use is actually in the `conan` script.